# What files does affect apt-get purge¿?

Tags: files, apt

I want to know before doing `apt-get purge <packet>` what files thats gonna have effect on.
The reverse thing would be, what packet do I have to do purge if I want to remove that file (`apt-file search <file>`), but my question is the first one.
Hope I made myself clear, thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `apt-get purge` is mostly identical to `apt-get remove`, but `purge` also deletes any configuration files. Often you will want to keep those as they can hold local changes that will be lost permanently if you delete them.

You can use `apt-file list <package_name>` to list out what files belong to a specific package. These files are the ones that will be deleted by `apt-get purge`. 
You can also use `dpkg-query -L <package_name>`